# How much time Dubai Ministry will take to give a employment visa?

Tags: visa, working-visas, uae

I got job offer in Dec'15 from one of Employer in Dubai, And I accepted the job offer on Jan'16. I hope they apply my visa on 25 Feb 2016, Now it's almost 6 weeks and they're saying they are still waiting for my visa so I want to know how much time Dubai Ministry will take to give a employment visa?

More on Can I check my visa status online based on my passport number?

Note: Company who offer me job is located in Dubai Silicon Oasis.

Thanks.